# sql search based on distance of lat lon coordinates

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select information from a mysql database based upon a distance to a specified lat/lon coordinate.

All values in the table will have a lat/lon column so using the user's current lat and lon I want to get all the results from the table that are let's say within a 1-mile proximity to the specified coordinate.

I have found this code but I would like someone to please explain it in very simple terms for example where am I putting the lat and lon value I want to be my focal point, how do I determine how large a radius to search and what each value in the query is?

```
SELECT *, (3959 * acos(cos(radians('".$lat."')) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos( radians(long) - radians('".$lng."')) + sin(radians('".$lat."')) * 
sin(radians(lat)))) 
AS distance 
FROM carpark WHERE distance < 15 ORDER BY distance
```

I understand this has already been asked but I still need to get a full understanding so I can impliment it in my code thank you very much in advance for your responce and apologise for any inconvinence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $lat and $lng are the focus co-ordinates, the 15 is the max range (1 in your example). Lat and Long are the column names in the table, which is called 'carpark'.
I'm not sure what units the distance is being calculated in.

Edit: looks like this calc is in miles. To search by kilometers instead of miles, replace 3959 with 6371

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you very much for your responce it helped a lot just one thing left do you know how i can determine the unit for the distance used

Comment: I think it is miles when using the 3959 constant. Use 6371 if you want kilometres. You can test by putting in two co-ordinates a known distance apart.